# start intent without onCreate {}

Tags: android, android-intent, oncreate

I have created a class which extends Gallery. There is no onCreate() method in super Class, and I'm unable to run my intent. 
This is my sample code:

```
 this.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
 Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ClassName.class);
 startActivity(intent);
}}
```

The following attempt also failed to work:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ThisClassName.this, ClassName.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: ok just creat a method and put the intent in the method. Then make an instance of the class and call the method. But remember to rap in a try, catch method. That should work

Comment: oh ok, so if the intent is not calling any other Activity then, just simply creat an instant and call the method, as @herom mentioned you cannot call the class with intent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, `startActivity();` is the method of **Activity** class, To run this method you have to `Context of Activity` or `Reference of Activity` , You can not run this method in other class as outside of Activity scope without having Activity reference for it.

Try,

```
<Activity_Name>.this.startActivity(intent);
```

or

```
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Here **mContext** is reference of your Activity class.

Answer (score 2):

As you wrote, you want to start an `Activity`, if your class does not inherit from `Activity` (which I guess, because otherwise you WOULD HAVE TO implement `onCreate()`) you won't be able to start it with an Intent at all....

Answer (score 0):

If your class is the extends of the main activity and you want to call the other activity from the main body of the class, just simply create a method in the other class, then call the method by making an instance of the class and call the method.

Since they have the same nature, that will work, But remember to rap the method call in a try and catch method, otherwise you may get some errors.

Answer (score 0):

`Gallery` is a `View` type if you will see its `Hirerchy` you will see that its `super` class is `View` and view does't have any onCreate method

to use your `CustomGallery`

you can use it from xml or from code

```
<com.mypackage.CustomGallery >
android:id...


 </com.mypackage.CustomGallery>
```